# How to get data from Post Method Response on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post

Hi guys I'm new to Flutter
I'm trying to fetch the data from http.post method using FutureBuilder and snapshot.data but it keeps returning CircularProgressIndicator which is means snapshot has no data.

```
Future postDataTransaksi() async {
  try {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://ignis.rumahzakat.org/donol/listTransaksi'),
        body: {
          '---': '---',
          '---': '---',
        },
        headers: {
          'access-token': '---'
        });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    } else {}
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

```
This is my post method code.
```

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: postDataTransaksi(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Container(child: Text(snapshot.data[0]['id']));
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              })
```

```
And this is how I try to fetch the data
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your builder to this:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
     return Container(child: Text(snapshot.data[0]['id']));
} else {
     return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

and also change your `future` to this"

```
Future<List> postDataTransaksi() async {
  try {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://ignis.rumahzakat.org/donol/listTransaksi'),
        body: {
          '---': '---',
          '---': '---',
        },
        headers: {
          'access-token': '---'
        });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return data;// <--- add this
    }

    return [];// <--- add this
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    return [];// <--- add this
  }
}
```

Comment: With `snapshot.data[0]['id']` it looks like the return value will be a list not a map.

Comment: how to make it return a map, Please help me

Comment: @FikryAhmadHaykhal Could you add your api response?